# How can I easily repeat an html element on a page thousands of times?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I repeat an HTML element thousands of times and append each to my web page?

For example, let's say I want to display the same word, `testing`, a thousand times on my page. Do I need to write out `<p>testing</p>` a thousand times in the source code or can I use a JavaScript function along the lines of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   <p>testing</p>
}
```

to more easily append `testing` to my web page 1k times?

Comment: You can use a loop, but you have to add the content to the `document` by either creating the element and using `appendChild` or by setting the contents to an existing element using `innerHTML`. Here is a [rough sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mL5he/) to help you get started.

Comment: `(new Array(1000)).join('<p>word</p>');`

Comment: **http://jsfiddle.net/LH38U/**

Comment: @adeneo You should post that as an answer. It's actually rather good since it eliminates the unnecessary DOM-accesses that the other answers perpetuate. Creating the content, then appending it to the DOM, would be much faster than a `for` loop that repeatedly appends to a node.

Answer (score 2):

Not best answer. but its good. good and simple way.

```
<p id="sample"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML += "<br>TEST";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding to the innerHTML of the `<body>` tag of your page.

```
for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += '<p>word</p>';
}
```

`document` refers to your page.

`getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` grabs all the elements on your page with the `<body>` tag (of which there should only be 1) and puts them into an array. The `[0]` grabs the first (0-index) element from this array.

`innerHTML` refers to the HTML inside the element.

So you're grabbing all the `<body>` tags on your page, choosing the first one, and appending `<p>word</p>` to its inner HTML 1000 times.